# Ledovid - Before or After Aleinu?

Tags: elul, tefilla, prayer-book, minhag

I noticed that in my Siddur as well as many others, "Ledovid" (what we say extra from Rosh Chodesh Elul until Shemini Atzeres) is placed right after the Yom by Shacharis davening. However, in every Shul I've ever been to, Ledovid is actually said after Aleinu.

So which is correct? Is there a Machlokes?

Comment: I've never seen the practice you've observed. In every shul I've ever been to, it's been said after the Shir Shel Yom.

Comment: @SethJ I think (based on the question) that yydl davens nusach sefard

Comment: @joel but see Issac's answer here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2612/5

Comment: @SethJ Right. Many (most?) nusach sefard places do it after aleinu during the week, and after shir shel yom after shacharit of shabbat (before keriat hatorah)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try [this audio from Rabbi Grunstein](http://download.yutorah.org/2010/1062/744756/Sefeira-before%20or%20after%20Aleinu.MP3) ([hat-tip Joel Rich](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2010/05/audio-roundup-xcv.html)) on Aleinu before/after Sefiras HaOmer.  I think the same logic applies.

As I recall from it: one school of thought is that Aleinu should be in the davening, somewhere near the end.  But you can add other prayers afterwards.

The other school of thought (prominent in Nusach Sefard, I think) is that Aleinu, about our faith, should be the very last message [okay there's kaddish] people get before leaving the sanctuary and going out to face the day in a large and spiritually-dangerous world.

Rabbi Grunstein concluded that if this is your custom that's great; if that's your custom that's great; not to make a huge deal about it (or scream at the chazan if he slips up).

Though I'd wonder with shofar-blowing and L'dovid if we'd want to leave people with that final message ...

Answer (score 0):

I can't shed any light on which practice is correct, but in the Nusach Sefard shul I davened in this morning, where the Yom is said before Torah reading on Shabbat, Ledovid was said right after the Yom.